# Convert input to integer before save in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a set of select inputs representing a users birthday: birthyear, birthmonth and birthday. I want to validate birthyear like this:

```
  validates_inclusion_of :birthyear, :in => Date.today.year-50..Date.today.year-12
```

So the user can be at least 12 years but at most 50 years when they are registering.

My problem is that the variable from the input is a string and not an integer.

So how can I convert the input to an integer? Is there any easier way to check the users age?

Comment: Are you getting a validation error with this rule or maybe some other error?   The api docs show validating an age field, no mention there of needed any conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have defined the `birthyear` db column as a string. Rails will convert the inut params to the appropriate type when assigned. So `user.new(params[:user])` will save `birthyear` in the type defined buy the db column type.

If you can't change the db column to an integer then try creating an array of the valid strings.

```
validates_inclusion_of :birthyear,
  :in => (Date.today.year-50..Date.today.year-12).map(&:to_s)
```

Now, bare in mind, in production, the model classes could get cached and you could have a case of the date range being wrong for the new year until you restart.

I would add this in the validate function and not use the inclusion validation to prevent this case.

```
def validate
  current_year = Date.today.year
  if birthyear && (birthyear.to_i <= current_year - 50 || birthyear.to_i >= current_year - 12)
    errors.add(:birthyear, "must be between 12 and 50 years of age")
  end
end
```

**Now, all of this assumes that the input coming in is a 4 digit year.**

Comment: God, you where right, rails converts it to integer if it is in the db, just switched and tested. Thank you! i feel so stupid.

Comment: No need to feel stupid. Rails does a *lot* behind the scenes and it is easy to get lost when something doesn't work as you expected.

Comment: It really does, and it is great but you tend to think you have to do it yourself so you make the easy things to do really hard. I think that is a curse from comming from PHP